# PDF Printer prints always default page size if program runs as service

Tags: windows, pdf, printing, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I have a problem with printing to any PDF printer selecting wrong page size if the printing program runs as service.

The computer is running Windows Server 2016. The problem appears with every PDF printer.

If I start the program directly printing works.

If I start the program as service page size is wrong.
The wrong page size is always the page size from printers default settings. If I change the default settings it will also change page size. But the printing result is never the page size the program sends.

What I already checked:

- Program runs in both variants with same user (not local or system account)
- Page size is selected automatically if started directly - I do not use the printer dialog or change any settings manually
- Printer has full rights (print, modify, ...) for Everyone
- There is no error during printing - it's just wrong result

Is there any setting I missed?

Comment: What is the printing program and how does it invoke the PDF printer?

Comment: Program is called Comos. I have no idea how it is invoked. The service is just a program in background waiting for a command (by a specific command file) which runs Comos with some parameters. In both ways (manual, service) the print command itself is fired by a button which has no further settings. So I cannot select page size - it should be selected automatically by the document settings.